# Passing method to a typescript decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass a method to a typescript decorator. I am able to do so when I do this as an inline arrow function. But I am not able to do this in the following way:

```
function preProcessor(preFn:any) {
    
    return function (
        target: any,
        propertyKey: string,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ) {        
        descriptor.value = function (param:any) {
            return preFn(param);
        }
    };
}

class C {
    @preProcessor(this.capitalize)
    methodA(str: any) {
        console.log(str)    }

  capitalize = (x:any)=>{return x.toUpperCase()}

}

var c = new C()
console.log(c.methodA("samurai..."))
```

**This works:**

```
@preProcessor((x:any)=>{return x.toUpperCase()})
```

Comment: This is not possible. When the decorator runs, there is no `this` yet. Your best bet would be to pass the *name* of the method, i.e. `@preProcessor('capitalize')`

Comment: How is sending name as a string going to work?  @Bergi

Comment: Then you can call `this[methodName]()` inside the decorated method

Comment: That seems to be working. One noob question though- I believe it's possible because `this` would refer to the context of the caller. Which is `class C` right?  Therefore it will work because capitalize is inside class C. Is that correct?

Comment: No, [it refers to `c`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572) or whatever you are calling `.methodA()` on.

Comment: @Bergi isn't that same as what I said? O.o? I mean `this` will hold scope of class c instance on which method was called, right?

Comment: I was just taking you literally - the instance `c` is not the same as the class object `C`. And there is no "scope" for object properties. The object `c` inherits `methodA` from `C.prototype`, and has an own property `capitalize`. Notice you can also do `c.methodA.call({capitalize() { return x.toLowerCase(); }}, "Ooops")` where `this` does not refer to `c` and it will call a different capitalise function.

Comment: @Bergi got it.. thanks